# How to get a tamed wolf in a minecart?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I've been spending a lot of time in making a Minecart bridge for my Wolf, but I couldn't really transport my Wolf in the Minecart. I tried everything, none of them worked.

How can I put a Tamed Wolf in a Minecart?

Comment: Why not use a lead?

Comment: This needs more detail, since it works for others. For example: About how fast was the minecart moving when it reaches the dog? What happened instead of collecting the dog, does it bounce back or go through? Etc.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you tried everything.

Lead the dog to the track using a leash, then seat the dog right next to the track:

[image]

Then run the minecart by the dog.

[image]